# How to find first and last value of a column in SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, inner-join, window-functions

I have a table having below schema

```
Item:Varchar
Date:Date
Quantity:Float
trasactionid:int
```

**Sample Data:**

| Item | Date | Quantity | transactionid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Part1 | 01-01-2023 | 10 | 3 |
| Part1 | 01-01-2023 | 15 | 5 |
| Part1 | 01-01-2023 | 17 | 2 |
| Part1 | 01-01-2023 | 13 | 6 |
| Part1 | 02-01-2023 | 13 | 7 |
| Part1 | 02-01-2023 | 1 | 8 |
| Part1 | 02-01-2023 | 22 | 10 |
| Part1 | 02-01-2023 | 5 | 12 |

I need to sort the data by transaction id and then find the unique part and date and Qty from first row of a group as Opening Balance and from last row as closing balance.

**Required Output**

| Item | Date | transactionid | OpeningBal | transactionid | ClosingBal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Part1 | 01-01-2023 | 2 | 17 | 6 | 13 |
| Part1 | 02-01-2023 | 7 | 13 | 12 | 5 |

I tried to use window funtion first_value and last value but unable to achieve the result

Comment: What is MySQL version?

Comment: SHow us the query you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT item, `date`, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN first_last.opening = test.trasactionid THEN test.trasactionid END) OpeningId,
       MAX(CASE WHEN first_last.opening = test.trasactionid THEN quantity END) OpeningBal, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN first_last.closing = test.trasactionid THEN test.trasactionid END) ColsingId,
       MAX(CASE WHEN first_last.closing = test.trasactionid THEN quantity END) ClosingBal
FROM test
JOIN (
  SELECT item, `date`, MIN(trasactionid) opening, MAX(trasactionid) closing
  FROM test
  GROUP BY 1,2
) first_last USING (item, `date`)
GROUP BY 1,2
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/QQlpAnJt

Comment: In my experience, self-joins are usually less effective than window functions to solve such requirement.

Comment: @GMB I agree. But OP have not told what is the server version..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about mySql syntax but many SQL engines supports `WITH` syntax and I think it will be very easy for you to translate. This is a way to resolve your problem:

```
WITH min_max AS (
  SELECT item, date, min(tran_id) AS min_id, max(tran_id) AS max_id
    FROM my_table
   GROUP BY item, date
)
SELECT item, date, min_id, my_table1.quantity, max_id, my_table2.quantity
  FROM min_max
  JOIN my_table AS my_table1
    ON min_max.min_id = my_table1.tran_id
  JOIN my_table AS my_table2
    ON min_max.max_id = my_table2.tran_id
```

If `WITH` syntax is not supported you can use `FROM (SELECT ...)` syntax

Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 5.5, this is a working solution for any version of `mysql`:

```
select t.Item, t.Date, t.opening_transaction, op.Quantity as OpeningBal, t.closing_transaction, oc.Quantity as ClosingBal 
from (
  select Item, Date, min(transactionid) as opening_transaction,
                   max(transactionid) as closing_transaction
  from mytable
  group by item, Date
) t
inner join mytable op on op.transactionid = t.opening_transaction
inner join mytable oc on oc.transactionid = t.closing_transaction
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/OfkefuxK)

Comment: This looks the same as the answer by @Julian, which was posted a while before (only the CTE is turned to a subquery).

Comment: That's correct @GMB, In this case do I have to delete it ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `first_value` and `last value` window functions, try the following:

```
select Item, Date_, transactionid_1, OpeningBal, transactionid_2, ClosingBal
from
(
  select Item, Date_, 
   min(transactionid) over (partition by Item, Date_) transactionid_1,
   first_value(Quantity) over (partition by Item, Date_ order by transactionid) OpeningBal,
   max(transactionid) over (partition by Item, Date_) transactionid_2,
   last_value(Quantity) over (partition by Item, Date_ order by transactionid range between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) ClosingBal,
  transactionid
 from table_name
) t
where transactionid = transactionid_1
order by Item, Date_
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Jr6UbcUU)

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions like so:

```
select item, date, 
    transation_id opening_transaction_id, balance opening_quantity,
    closing_transaction_id, closing_quantity
from (
    select t.*, 
        max(transation_id)    over(partition by item, date) closing_transaction_id,
        first_value(quantity) over(partition by item, date order by transaction_id desc) closing_quantity,
        row_number()          over(partition by item, date order by transaction_id) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

The subquery computes the date and the quantity of the last daily transaction , using `max()` and `first_value()` respectively. It also identifies the row that correspond to the first transaction, using `row_number()`. Then, the outer query just filters on the top record per group, which already contains the information we need.

The upside of this method is that it avoids aggregation and self-joins (which are less efficient in most cases) - and it has as few window function calls as possible.